# Linux "watch" command showing last 30 lines of nft list ruleset

Tags: bash, command-line, tail, watch

I want to constantly see last 30 lines of code "nfc list ruleset" in Debian Bash. Something like this:

```
watch -n 1 nft list ruleset | tail -n 30
```

But above code doesn't show last 30 lines of "nfc" command output, it shows blank screen.

Comment: please update the question to expand on what you mean by *`doesn't work`* ... error message? no ouput? wrong output? too much output? hangs? something else?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution while typing question

```
watch "bash -c 'sudo nft list ruleset | tail -n 30'"
```

Answer (score 0):

just:

```
watch -n 1 'nft list ruleset | tail -n 30'
```

Most `watch` implementations these days invoke a shell to interpret the concatenation of their arguments as shell code as if using `eval`. Some have a `-x` options to cut the middle man and run the command directly so

So:

```
watch foo bar
```

is actually the same as:

```
watch -x sh -c 'foo bar'
```

And your:

> ```
> watch "bash -c 'sudo nft list ruleset | tail -n 30'"
> ```

Is like:

```
watch -x sh -c "bash -c 'sudo nft list ruleset | tail -n 30'"
```

With that `bash` invocation totally unnecessary as `sh` can do piping just as well as bash and generally more efficiently.

You might want to make it:

```
sudo watch 'nft list ruleset | tail -n 30'
```

Rather than:

```
watch 'sudo nft list ruleset | tail -n 30'
```

even if `watch` or `tail` don't need superuser privileges to avoid the `sudo` overhead at each iteration (and filling up your audit logs).

Comment: OK. That's definitely better answer.